# How to remove duplicates from a PHP string separated by "X"?

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
13:BOOT2700        X;27
13:BOOT2700        X;27
13:BOOT2700        X;27
13:BOOT2700        X;27
13:BOXER1136       X;11.36
13:BOXER1364       X;13.64
13:BOXER1591       X;15.91
13:BOXER909        X;9.09
...
```

I would like to remove the duplicates of data[0] and remove the spaces and the "X" at the end of the string. For the second part it works correctly but I can't delete the duplicates. I tried this code but they remain. It shows me each time the first values while they are identical.

In the end I would like this:

```
13:BOOT2700;27
13:BOXER1136;11.36
13:BOXER1364;13.64
13:BOXER1591;15.91
13:BOXER909;9.09
```

How can I do it?
Thanks for your help

```
<?php

$file = "BI6_20211214_0905_15000.txt";
    
        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== false) {
                  

                
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {        

                    $uniqueStr = implode('X', array_unique(explode('X', $data[0]))); //doesn't work

                    $clean_name = str_replace(' ', '', $data[0]);
                    $clean_name2 = str_replace('X', '', $clean_name);
                    
                        echo $clean_name2; //13:BOOT2700
                        echo ("<br>"); 

                    } 
                }
                fclose($handle);              
     
 
echo "good !";


?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include what the final result should look like?

Comment: It's done @zedfoxus

Comment: Can you edit your PHP code such that it meets the requirements of being a [mre]? There is a lot of code you've included that's unnecessary for reproducing your issue.

Comment: Like what? If you take the csv code you put it in a file that you call "BI6_test" and you put it in the folder of your .php file it works without worries

Comment: Instead of `str_replace` try using with regex `preg_replace('/\s+X/i', '', $string);` for example, that will replace all spaces then the X...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bossman, it works for this removal

Comment: I just simplified my code to the maximum @esqew

Comment: @Eric27: The easiest way to remove duplicates is to make an array() from the single strings and then filter out the duplicates with array_unique().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is read into an array with [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). With [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) and [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) the spaces and the X are removed from each line. [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique) then removes the duplicate entries.

```
$array = file('input.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$array = array_map(function($v){return preg_replace('/ +X;/',';',$v);}, $array);
$array = array_unique($array);
```

The result is an array.

```
array (
  0 => "13:BOOT2700;27",
  4 => "13:BOXER1136;11.36",
  5 => "13:BOXER1364;13.64",
  6 => "13:BOXER1591;15.91",
  7 => "13:BOXER909;9.09",
)
```

If a file is required as a result, the array can be converted into a string with implode and written to a file with file_put_contents.

```
$str = implode("\r\n",$array);
file_put_contents('input.csv', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the entire code simplified and with comments that can help OP and others understand how you can process that.

I have 2 files:

input.txt

```
13:BOOT2700        X;27
13:BOOT2700        X;28
13:BOOT2700        X;29
13:BOOT2700        X;29
13:BOXER1136       X;11.36
13:BOXER1364       X;13.64
13:BOXER1591       X;15.91
13:BOXER909        X;9.09
```

When you run the code below, its result will be

```
===> Processing input.txt
Result:
13:BOOT2700;27
13:BOXER1136;11.36
13:BOXER1364;13.64
13:BOXER1591;15.91
13:BOXER909;9.09
```

input2.txt

```
13:BOOT111         X;27
13:BOOT2700        X;29
13:BOOT2700        X;29
13:BOXER1136       X;11.36
13:BOXER1364       X;13.64
13:BOXER1591       X;15.91
13:BOXER909        X;9.09
```

Its output will be

```
===> Processing input2.txt
Result:
13:BOOT111;27
13:BOOT2700;29
13:BOXER1136;11.36
13:BOXER1364;13.64
13:BOXER1591;15.91
13:BOXER909;9.09
```

## Code

```
<?php

# Remove byte order mark (BOM)
function remove_utf8_bom($text) {
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}

# get list of all files
$dir   = 'your-path/';
$allFiles = scandir($dir);

# process each file
foreach($allFiles as $file) {

    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) {
        continue;
    }

    if (strpos($file, 'BI6_') === false) {
        continue;
    }

    echo "===> Processing $file\n";
    $file = $dir.$file;
    $filename = basename( $file );

    # stores unique items like 13:BOOT2700, 13:BOXER1136 etc.
    $processedItems = array();

    # stores lines in the format we need
    $finalResult = array();

    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    if ($handle === false) {
        echo "Problem opening $file. Skipping.\n";
        continue;
    }

    # read each line
    while(!feof($handle)) {
        $line = fgets($handle);
        $line = remove_utf8_bom($line);

        # skip empty lines
        if (strlen(trim($line)) === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        # split by X;, trim the first part
        $lineSplit = explode('X;', $line);
        $lineSplit[0] = trim($lineSplit[0]);

        # check if the first part (such as 13:BOOT2700) is processed already
        # if so, don't do anything else
        if (in_array($lineSplit[0], $processedItems) === true) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            # store the first part in processed items and create the newly
            # formatted line; store that in final result
            $processedItems[] = $lineSplit[0];
            $finalResult[] = $lineSplit[0] . ';' . $lineSplit[1];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);

    # show the final result
    echo "Result:\n";
    foreach ($finalResult as $x) {
        echo $x;
    }
}
 
echo "Done";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanations. When I run your code I get an error `"Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 60"`. It's this line: `"$finalResult[] = $lineSplit[0] . ';' . $lineSplit[1];"`.

Comment: Do you have any line that doesn’t have X;?

Comment: No all have the same format

Comment: Just before the line that’s throwing the notice, type echo $line;  Run the program again. That’ll tell you the line that was being processed at the time. Let me know the content of that line.

Comment: I put in the question a picture of what it generates for me

Comment: @Eric27 I know what's going on. You have csv.php in the same folder. So the program tries to process that file also. Do all filenames that you want to process contain the words `BI6_` in its filename?

Comment: Yes, I call them BI6_ so that it only performs this treatment on these files

Comment: Easy enough, @Eric27. I have added `if (strpos($file, 'BI6_') === false) { continue; }` in the code in my answer so that it processes only files that have `BI6_` in its name.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now